# Inline form elements within non-inline form in Bootstrap 3?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is it possible to have certain form elements within a Bootstrap form be inline, while the rest are not?

In my form, I want to make everything take up the full 6 columns, except city, state, and ZIP should occupy a single line. See code below:

```
<form id="main-form" role="form">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="bill-name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="bill-name"
        placeholder="Full name">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="bill-company">Company</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="bill-company"
        placeholder="Company name">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="bill-address1">Address</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="bill-address1"
        placeholder="Street address">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="bill-address2">Address 2</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="bill-address2"
        placeholder="Suite, building number, etc.">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="bill-city">City</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="bill-city"
        placeholder="City">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="bill-state">State</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="bill-state"
        placeholder="State">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the beauty of the nestable grid. The result isn't truly inline, but I think it's more effective.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
        <label for="bill-city">City</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="bill-city" placeholder="City">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
        <label for="bill-state">State</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="bill-state" placeholder="State">
    </div>
</div>
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/aya0pp1j/2)

Note that this only applies to `sm` and above screen widths. You could change the class to `col-xs-6` to go all the way down with it.