# How can I give width to nested inline form elements with Bootstrap 3?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a strange problem with the widths of columns inside a form. I'm trying to nest an form-inline class inside a form-group. I think I've tried not only changing everything at run time from Chrome's inspect window but also every answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18429121/inline-form-nested-within-horizontal-form-in-bootstrap-3), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23662873/how-do-i-adjust-bootstrap-3-inline-form-width) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26685584/inline-form-elements-within-non-inline-form-in-bootstrap-3) without getting a good result.

Here's my code:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">

<fieldset>

.....

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Tel. Celular</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="form-inline">
            <!-- <div class="form-group col-sm-4"> -->
                <label class="sr-only" for="cell_area_code">Cod. Area</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cell_area_code" placeholder="Cod. Area">
            <!-- </div> -->
            <!-- <div class="form-group col-sm-8"> -->
                <label class="sr-only" for="cell_number">N&uacute;mero</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cell_number" placeholder="N&uacute;mero">
            <!-- </div> -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

.....

</fieldset>

</form>
```

and here's the result:[image]

Why doesn't the columns occupy 100% of the width? Also, if I enable those commented divs, here's what I get:[image]
... and there's no difference in width... just overlapping before of the negative margins from the "form-group" class.

What is going on?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: http://www.bootply.com/DoJAJ0u4uJ# please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your third row should look like this:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="container">
  ...
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Tel. Celular</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="cell_area_code">Cod. Area</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cell_area_code" placeholder="Cod. Area" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="sr-only" for="cell_number">N&uacute;mero</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cell_number" placeholder="N&uacute;mero">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: I had to do some small adjustments but in general it worked. Thanks a lot!